# How to compute Straight Skeletons using Python?

Tags: python, polygon, geometry, skeleton, computational-geometry

Is there a Python package which provides an implementation of a Straight Skeleton algorithm?

I'm aware that the open source (C++) project [CGALcontains an implementation](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Straight_skeleton_2/index.html) but it seems like [cgal-bindings doesn't include this CGAL package](https://code.google.com/p/cgal-bindings/wiki/Package_wrappers_available).

In any case, I would prefer a pure Python implementation which I could modify/extend to suit my needs.

While an implementation that can handle polygons with holes would be preferable, it's not strictly necessary.

Comment: Have you tested  pySkeleton or [Skeletron](https://github.com/migurski/Skeletron)?

Comment: I tried pySkeleton. The GUI application didn't work for me and I haven't found time yet to check if the code is salvageable

Comment: import polygon vertices = [(0,0), (0,5), (5,5), (5,0)]
edges = [(0,1), (1,2), (2,3), (3,0)] p = polygon.Polygon(vertices, edges)
skeleton_graph = p.straight_skeleton()
__________________________________________________
While executing above i got the following error:
_________ Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\pySkeleton\pySkeleton\test.py", line 6, in <module> p = polygon.Polygon(vertices, edges) File "C:\pySkeleton\pySkeleton\polygon.py", line 44, in __init__ self.vertices = map(Point,vertices)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you can modify [pySkeleton](http://vision.mas.ecp.fr/Personnel/teboul/pySkeleton.php) by Olivier Teboul to suit your needs.

I haven't had the chance to look at the actual code but from what he says it should be *pure Python*.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [pySkeleton](http://vision.mas.ecp.fr/Personnel/teboul/pySkeleton.php) as follows:

```
from pySkeleton import polygon

vertices = [(0,0), (0,5), (5,5), (5,0)]
edges = [(0,1), (1,2), (2,3), (3,0)]

p = polygon.Polygon(vertices, edges)
skeleton_graph = p.straight_skeleton()
```

You get a Graph-Object with Nodes and Arcs, which you can access simply by:

```
nodes = skeleton_graph.nodes
arcs = skeleton_graph.arcs
```

As it says in the pySkeleton readme.txt, the polygon vertices needs to be in clockwise-order. 
For holes within the polygon, vertices needs to be in counter clockwise-order.

```
vertices = [(25.0, 15.0), (45.0, 15.0), (45.0, 35.0), (25.0, 35.0), # polygon
            (30.0, 20.0), (30.0, 30.0), (40.0, 30.0), (40.0, 20.0)] # hole in polygon

edges = [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 0), # polygon
         (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 4)] # hole in polygon
```

Remark:
For more complex polygons with 100+ vertices and edges pySkeleton is unfeasibly slow. Besides that I receive strange results for some polygons. I assume that it does not work correctly in all cases.

Nonetheless, big thanks to Olivier Teboul for this library.