# Travel planning - Finding farthest points of a polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, algorithm, route, skeleton, computational-geometry

I’d like to organize a tour around the lake with 2 objectives:

- maximise the length of shores to view
- minimise travel distance

In order to do so I can:

1. Pick 2 most remote points on the lake in terms of travelling distance
2. Define ‘left’ and ‘right’ shores of the lake
3. Travel at equal distance between shores from A to B

[image]

What is the best way to find these 2 points?

UPDATE ON ORIGINAL Q:

The approach I am using is to place multiple random points and calculate Euclidean minimum spanning tree.

[image]

Iterate trough all pairs of points/nodes in order to find a couple with longest distance. Picture shows distance where destination is point at the North.
It works but a bit cumbersome, so I am looking for ideas. Raster or vector will do.

[image]

This is about never ending discussion re polygon length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Non-Convex Polygon**

You should draw the Medial Axis Transform (skeleton or center-line) of the polygon. Options to do this:

1. [Create Centerlines](http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/UserGuide/createCenterlines.htm)
2. use [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/3.2/doc_html/cgal_manual/Straight_skeleton_2/Chapter_main.html) with arcobjects

Then utilize the centerlines calculate network based distanced between any two points and find the farthest ones.

**Convex Polygon**

The simplest, albeit not the most efficient way is to calculate (arcpy) pair-wise distances between each vertices of your polygon feature (Lake) and extract the greatest one. The complexity would be o(n^2), with n the number of vertices, for each polygon.

If you don't want to do coding (python), create a model with:

1. Feature To Point GP tool
2. DISTANCE BETWEEN POINTS TOOL (from [Hawth's Analysis Tool](http://www.spatialecology.com/htools/pntdistmatrix.php))

**Similiar Questions**

[How to compute Straight Skeletons using Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136143/how-to-compute-straight-skeletons-using-python)

[Simplifying polygons to linestring](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177/simplifying-polygons-to-linestring)

[Find tunnel 'center line'?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2775/find-tunnel-center-line)

Comment: I think this will need a raster rather than vector solution, and so I would look at [Cost Path](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/cost-path.htm) first.

Comment: @Farid Cher  This will pick point B and most southern point

Comment: +1 @PolyGeo Although I am using vector approach to this, do you think I have to update my post with it?

Comment: My bad. I didn't notice non-convexity of your example.

Comment: @FelixIP My preference is usually a vector approach for accuracy, but this looks like a problem that needs a more pragmatic raster solution.  Whichever you seek (at least in the first instance), I think you should say explicitly in your question.

Comment: @FlexiIP You need to calculate the medial axis (skeleton) of the polygon (see updated answer)