# How to create "roof line" for a general polygon area?

Tags: dem, geometry, watershed, geometric-network, flow-accumulation

I have a polygon with an arbitrary shape ( assume that it is well-formed with no self intersection, no duplicated points etc), and I need to subdivide the polygon into sub-polygons like how one would define roof on top of a building. 
How can I do that in any GIS software, or through any open source libraries, or through any algorithm?

The reason why I'm asking this is because for my flat terrain ( with 2D shape unknown obviously), I have to manually enforce [artificial gradients at appropriate places](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/286034/1261), so that the water can flow to the neighboring cells correctly when I am applying D8 implementation to calculate the flow accumulation. So the most intuitive places for sub-division would be the places where roof lines are taking along.

I would be interested to know is there any algorithm that one can use for this, and also is there any C++ open source libraries implementation for this ( I don't want to reinvent the wheel); is GDAL or CGAL or any geometrical algorithm already has this implementation?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164863/travel-planning-finding-farthest-points-of-a-polygon

Comment: "Like how one would define roof on top of a building" is rather vague. Can you edit your question to include a definition, or perhaps some illustration, of what you mean here?

Comment: @csk, no I can't define it precisely, but there is no need for me to do so; I've explained why I need such a roof line method further into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're asking for is skeletonisation

See Wikipedia on [straight skeleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straight_skeleton) and [topological skeleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_skeleton)

This will give the effect of a sloping roof, even on irregular shaped polygons (I'm not sure how well it works with donuts e.g. atriums). It's based on voronoi meshes.

I haven't tried it myself, but grass has an algorithm called `v.voronoi` with the -s option [to produce skeletons](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/v.voronoi.html), although it only appears to work with point layers. SAGA has a similar module but for rasters.

see also [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/171145/55203) for other options (e.g. i think [postgis sf-gcal extension](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_StraightSkeleton.html) can do this)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33887/finding-centrelines-from-polygons-in-qgis) thread. It's a method for deriving the centerline of polygons, and to me the product does look like rooftops.