# Minimum Bounding Rectangle

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sink

I am stuck in a seemingly simple but strange thing. I am finding sinks in an area by LiDAR data. after finding the sinks, I want to determine their elongation and for this purpose I use minimum bounding rectangle tool. I have the area and the length of the rectangles, and I divide the area by length to obtain width. after having the width, I divide the length by width. But the problem is that I get a very high number for ELG and it does not look like it. I will attach the pictures .sink
[image: ELG]

Comment: Shape_Length is the total length of the geometry, not one side of the rectangle. I don't know if there's a faster way than pulling the corner coordinates and calculating the length and width. Ah ha! See this [Q&A](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222345/identify-shape-of-the-polygons-elongation-roundness-etc)

Comment: If Shape_Length is the total length of the geometry, how can I obtain the big length and simply the width?

Comment: Please read the linked question and answer for an alternative method of calculating the elongation. Otherwise, you'll have to retrieve coordinates of 3 corners of the rectangle to calculate the length and width yourself.

Comment: The ArcGIS tool, Minimum Bounding Geometry, with RECTANGLE_BY_WIDTH or RECTANGLE_BY_AREA outputs the Width and Length of the MBR. You shouldn't need to calculate it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I read the linked question and used te method.